# Nodejs response is sent as string instead of an JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm trying to send a JSON object with a response in a 403 event, that contains token expiration info, amongst others, to the client. However, for some reason the response is sent as a string object instead of JSON.

The response looks like this:

[image: HTTP Response]

Here are the relevant functions.

This is from the server:

```
function checkYourPrivilege(checkAdmin, bearerHeader, res, reg, next){
        if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
                var bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
                bearerToken = bearer[1];
                jwt.verify(bearerToken, secret, function(err, decoded) {
                        console.log(decoded);
                        if(err){
                                return res.json({ success:false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token'});
                        }else{
                                if(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 < decoded.expires)){
                                        if(checkAdmin){
                                                if(decoded.privileges.admin){
                                                        console.log("Tokenisi vanhentuu" + Math.abs(decoded.expires - Math.floo$
                                                        reg.decoded = decoded;
                                                        next();
                                                }else{
                                                        console.log("et ole admin");
                                                        return res.status(403).send({
                                                          success: false,
                                                          tokenstatus: "valid",
                                                          message: "Not admin"
                                                        });
                                                }
                                        }else{
                                                console.log("Tokenisi vanhentuu" + Math.abs(decoded.expires - Math.floor(Date.n$
                                                reg.decoded = decoded;
                                                next();
                                        }
                                }else{
                                        console.log("Token Expired");
                                        return res.status(403).send({
                                                  success: false,
                                                  tokenstatus: "valid",
                                                  message: "Not admin"
                                        });
                                }
                        }
                });
        } else {
                console.log('ei tokenia');
                return res.status(403).send({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'No token provided.'
                });
        }
};
```

This is from the client:

```
.factory('authInterceptorService', ['$q', '$location', '$localStorage', function($q, $location, $localStorage){
        return {
                'request': function (config){
                        console.log(config);
                        config.headers = config.headers || {};
                        if ($localStorage.accessToken) {
                                config.headers.Authorization = 'bearer ' + $localStorage.accessToken;
                        }
                        return config;
                },
                'responseError': function(response){
                        if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                                console.log(response);
                                $location.path('/');
                        }
                        return $q.reject(response);
                }
        };
}])
```

Comment: JSON is a string.

Comment: JSON is always sent as a string between machines. Just use `JSON.parse()` to turn it back into a object on the client side. For the record, there's no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a notation standard, not a object type. So standard javascript objects can be written as a string formatted as JSON.

Comment: Holy moly I feel stupid now. I'll appologize for the whole world before crawling back to my cave -.-

Comment: @nyoatype You should still do what Vitamine is suggesting. If you use res.json it will send the data with the correct content-type and AngularJS will parse it for you automatically. No reason to use JSON.parse().

Answer (score 2):

Try use 
`res.status(403).json({})` instead of
`res.status(403).send({})`